Чому є слово «край», яке, якщо додати суфікс «-ина» утворює слово «країна», у якому «и» вимовляється як «і»?
Не знаходив нічого щодо цього.

а чому ви вирішили, що додається -ин, а не -ін?

Край, крайній, крайнощі, краєвид, країна, окраїна та ін. Тут, або маємо два суфікси, або звукозміну в словотворчих іменникових суфіксах на твердий наприкінцевий приголосний основи. Уточніть ваше запитання та проведіть власну дослідну роботу.

"а чому ви вирішили, що додається -ин, а не -ін? – " бо такого суфікса в такому контексті не додають.

Було би непогано зазначити джерела, котрі твердять про вимову ї як йі в цьому випадку.
Декотрі особи зазначають, що в цьому випадку, де є протиславлення між ґрупами твердою і іншими, і і ї вимовляються як и або тяжїють до цього.
Приклади.

Олекса Синявський : Норми української літературної мови → ОРТОЕПІЯ І ПРАВОПИС. → § 117 і, и
Вимова звуків і й и не завсіди відповідає правописним і й и, а до того обидва ці звуки визначаються ще й літерою ї.

Правописне наголошене і в назвуці в деяких народніх словах вимовляється як и: інший, іноді, інде, істик, іскра, іграшка, ірод, іч вимовляються як инший…, хоч, треба сказати, це одна з можливих вимов, бо вимовляються вони й з і.

Правописне і та ї вимовляються близько до и (йи) в таких випадках, коли вони в певних закінченнях, аналогічних до закінчень із и:

у всіх м’яких прикметниках відповідно до твердих закінчень: синій, безкраїми... (вимовляються синьий, безкрайими див. § 52)

у наростках -їна, -їха, -їще, -їсько, -їк, -їн, -їкий, -їнський, -їстий: Україна (вимовл. Украйина), Соловʼїха, гноїще, боїсько, покоїк, Маріїн, соловʼїний, український, троїстий… (порівн. долина, багнище, столик, Ганнин, качиний, танцюристий…)

у дієслівних закінченнях без наголосу: стоїмо (вимовл. стойимо), го́їти, озбро́ївся… (але під наголосом стоїть, напоїти… з йі).






Микола Погрібний : Орфоепічний словник → Вимова голосних звуків

[…]
З  наближенням до [и] вимовляється також [і] в закінченнях називного й орудного відмінків однини та непрямих відмінків множини прикметників мʼякої групи та порядкового числівника третій:

[си́нʼіиі̆], [беизкра́јіиі̆], [тре́тʼіиі̆] — називний відм. чол. роду;
[си́нʼіим], [беизкра́јіим], [тре́тʼіим] — орудний відм. однини чол. й середн. роду;
[си́нʼіих], [беизкра́јіих], [тре́тʼіих] — родовий і місцевий відм. множини;
[си́нʼіим], [беизкра́јіим], [тре́тʼіим] — давальний відм. множини;
[си́нʼіими], [беизкра́јіими], [тре́тʼіими] — орудний відм. множини.

Так само вимовляється1 [і] в закінченнях присвійних займенників мій, твій, свій:

[мојіим] — орудний відм. однини;
[мојіих] — род. і місц. відм. множини;
[мојіим] — дав. відм. множини;
[мојіими] — орудн. відм. множини.

Без нахилу до [и] вимовляється [і] тільки в закінченнях

місцевого відм. однини чол. й середнього роду: у [си́нʼім], [беизкра́јім], [тре́тʼім], [мојім];
давального й місцевого відм. жіночого роду: [си́нʼіі̆], [беизкра́јіі̆], [тре́тʼіі̆], [мојіі̆]
та називоного відм. множини: [си́нʼі], [беизкра́јі], [тре́тʼі], [мојі].

Після [ј] широку вимову [і] маємо в ряді суфіксів: [крајіина], [геиројіинʼа], [во́јіин], [гно́јіишче], [виибо́јіистиі̆], [марʼіјіин], [го́јіити] та ін. Основна форма цих суфіксів -ин(а), -ин(я), -ин, -ищ(е), -ист(ий), -ин, -и(ти). Під впливом [ј] звук [и], що є в основі цих суфіксів, звужується до [іи].



Тут не згадані закінчення іменників, хоча вони, як на мене, сюди теж входять, бо існують щонайменше такі пари:

Правопис 2019 → Ⅱ. Правопис закінчень відмінювальних слів → Ⅲ відміна → § 92. Однина

[…]
Примітка 1. Іменники на -ть після приголосного, а також слова кров, любо́в, о́сінь, сіль, Білору́сь, Русь у родовому відмінку однини можуть набувати як варіант закінчення -и: гі́дности, незале́жности, ра́дости, сме́рти, че́сти, хоро́брости; кро́ви, любо́ви, о́сени, со́ли, Білору́си, Ру́си́.



Можна звернути увагу на правопис Желехівського, де скорїш за всього і запровадили ї майже в сучасному розуміннї:

там правило про -и поширюються на інші слова жіночого роду: річ-и;
розрізняють тверді і мʼякі і: синїй.

Як не дивно, але знаннє моск*вської вам чутливо допоможе: де там замість ї і і пишуть и, то тут скорїш за всього вимова як йи і ьи відповідно, пор.: троистий, Украина ~ Ukraina, соловьи, синий, воин, моим ~ moim [і як підтвердження в моем] ітд. Можливо, це була одна з мотивацій, крім деякого польського впливу, запровадження ї як такого сѵмбола.
Це вже більше діалектично, але при вимові стандартної української мовець при [і] може мати вимову як [и] також в словах, що:

Є чужоземними: фиґура. Це особливо помітно за правописом щодо ґрецьких слів переважно реліґійної тематики і що запозичені напряму або без латини як посередника: Вавилон, єпископ, диякон ітд. Хоча зазвичай тут зберігаємо і: логіка, діалог. Правило девʼятки, що взагалї має за основу польську фонолоґію, тут служить як дуже компромісний варіянт, а тому також є суперечливим і заскладним.
Що етѵмолоґічно походить від ы чи и, декотрі вже згадані вище і що на початку слова: ірод, іноді. Тут знов в більшостї випадків допоможе моск*вська і добра частина словʼянських мов. Це не обовʼязвко на початку слова: ні як в рядках гѵмна ні слава, ні воля, що може мати вимови ни, пизда ~ пізда ітд.

Основна причина такого явища скорїш в тому, що українська мала проміжок, де ы та и (тоді як і) злилися. Це працює і в зворотний бік: и → і, але переважно це в бік и.

Нотатки від себе

Що насправдї не дивно, бо основа чинних закінчень прикметників зазвичай походять від займенників.


Дякую за відповідь! Значить "Україна" годиться вимовляти як "Украйина"?
"Було би непогано зазначити джерела, котрі твердять про вимову ї як йі в цьому випадку."
Так твердять усі нинішні мовознавці та навчальні заклади.

@meleten Прошу. Як на мене, наразї це довільна варіяція. Тому можна вимовляти через йі або йи, але другий спосіб обґрунтований також будовою слова.
